# How do I debug the Flow declarations?

Tags: flowtype

It seems like my [declarations] are not being read, or maybe the .flowconfig file? Is there a command to dump all read declarations? Thankful for any tips. ^^

Comment: Can you be more specific here? What is your flowconfig like, do you mean files from flow-typed dir or node_modules? What is the current behaviour you're experiencing?

Comment: @Brianzchen I'm not sure my flowconfig is even read. Even introducing deliberate syntax errors do not change the behaviour. I wanted a verbose debug dump to see what config Flow actually picked up.